# using toString() in domain class in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Actually i want to return a String representation of an object of Organization class by using toString() method.please someone help me how to do this. how to return an object inside toString() function??

```
package com.ashwin

class Organization {


    String orgName
    String orgEsta
    String orgLogo
    String orgDesc
    String orgLoc



    static constraints = {
    }

    String toString(){
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: toString(), as its name indicates, and its javadoc clearly say, must return a String. Not an Organization. It must be public, too. Your question doesn't make sense. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

Comment: ok then how to write all the datatypes in this toString() method??

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings (i.e. orgName, orgEsta, etc.) together? Seriously, read the Java tutorial, or any introductory Java book. They all cover that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html, http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Answer (score 2):

I think the '@ToString' Groovy annotation is what you are looking for:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html

Comment: btw: there are many other helpful annotations like @Cannonical - just take a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.ashwin

import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString
class Organization {

String orgName
    String orgEsta
    String orgLogo
    String orgDesc
    String orgLoc

}
```

By default only properties are added to the output, but we can include fields as well with the annotation attribute `includeFields=true.`

So in this case your annotation will be:

```
// includeFields to not only output properties, but also field values.
    @ToString(includeNames=true, includeFields=true)
```

You can exclude field also

```
@ToString(includeNames=true, includeFields=true, excludes='orgLoc')
```

To check many other available options, see this [groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html) documentation

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
String toString(){
       this.dump()
    }
```

Generates a detailed dump string of an object showing its class, hashCode and fields.